# How to set the default table export format in MySQL workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

While exporting a table using **MySQL workbench**, the default type is ALWAYS `CSV`. I don't usually export a table in `CSV` format. Is there a way to change this default to be `SQL insert` ?

I circled the export button in the attached image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, but it uses (preserves) the last type you used with the Data Export.