# How do I open in Excel data exported from MySQL workbench?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mysql, export, mysql-workbench

When clicking to Export Data, the default format is CSV, but when the data element is text that contains a double quote and/or newline, such characters are treated by common readers (e.g. Excel) as an end of the element, with all sorts of formatting and document structure messed up, lots of new lines inserted, etc.  Is there something I can change about the export format, or Excel's import, that makes this (exporting from MySQL Workbench and opening in Excel) work?

[image: Export Data button]

(image from [here](https://superuser.com/q/771176/91971))